# KeyEventDispatcher and focus

Tags: java, swing, focus, keyboard-events

I'd like to add keyboard shortcuts to my game that uses SWING. So far I've been using the following code:

```
KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager()
            .addKeyEventDispatcher(new KeyEventDispatcher() {


                @Override
                public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent e) { ... }
```

For testing purposes I'd like to create two instances of this application (testing network play). The problems is that the non-focused window grabs the focus when I use the hotkeys. (The window that was created later.)

I suspect that the problem is that

```
KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager()
```

is a static method (both instances are started from the same JVM).

The only other option I could be thinking of was letting every component delegate their key-events to the ancestor JFrame, and handle them there at one place, but this would involve lots of boiler-place code, and I think this would be an ugly solution.

Also, the problems wouldn't occur during normal gameplay, it only annoys me while I'm testing.

Comment: this is basic property of todays Native OS's, last opened window by default is focus ownser

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I'd like to add keyboard shortcuts to my game that uses SWING

Then you should be using [Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html).

Comment: This was the second option that I was kind of averse of, but it seems there's no way around it. (Maybe with the WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT option it's not that bad after all.)

Comment: Key Bindings are the most flexible IMO. They are finicky though. Especially if your pressed and released Actions are different, make sure you test it a lot. I've had problems with them, especially on OS X. The Command key (both with getDefaultMenuMask() and KeyEvent.META_MASK) in particular has some bizarre behavior.

Comment: Actually I realized that my previous comment was kind of stupid: what I meant at the time of writing the original post was using traditional KeyListeners. Keybindings are totally different, because they don't give you a KeyEvent objects, like KeyListeners do. This is caused me some trouble, because I was delegating my events to other components "manually" (not considering the component layout hierarchy), and with the rewrite I had nothing to delegate. I'm not saying it's too much work to change, but it dictates a different "architecture".